# vb.net how to select combobox.items(name)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Can someone help me get through with this. Basically what I want to happen is by default, my combobox.text = "- SELECT -" then if combobox_dropdown ... combobox1.items.add("yes"), combobox1.items.add("n/a)

PS: Sub check_BIR is my first trial reference

```
Private Sub combo_UOM_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combo_BIR.DropDown
    combo_BIR.Items.Clear()
    combo_BIR.Items.Add("YES")
    combo_BIR.Items.Add("N/A")
End Sub

 Private Sub combo_UOM_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combo_BIR.DropDownClosed
     If (Not combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 0 Or Not combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 1) Then
         combo_BIR.Items.Clear()
         combo_BIR.Items.Add("- SELECT - ")
         combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 0
     End If
 End Sub

Sub check_BIR()
    If touchBIR = True Then
        If combo_BIR.Items.Contains("- SELECT - ") And (MsgBox("BIR Attached?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)) = vbYes Then
            combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 0
        Else
            combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 1
        End If
    End If

    If touchBIR = False Then
        If combo_BIR.Items.Contains("- SELECT - ") And (MsgBox("BIR Form attached?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)) = vbYes Then
            combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 1
        Else
            combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = 2
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim index1 As Integer = combo_BIR.FindString("YES")
    Dim index2 As Integer = combo_BIR.FindString("N/A")

    If combo_BIR.Items.Contains("- SELECT - ") And (MsgBox("BIR Attached?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)) = vbYes Then
        combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = index1
    Else
        combo_BIR.SelectedIndex = index2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it that you think your users are smart enough to work out how to use a `TextBox` or a `Button` but their intelligence stops short of being able to decipher a `ComboBox` without explicit instruction? Seriously, the idea of putting "- SELECT - " there is simply because you can and not because it serves any useful purpose. Do you really think anyone who has ever used a computer needs to be told to select an item and, if they really are that stupid, is that one word going to be enough? You're far from the only person to have this idea but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Common mistakes by users is that they might miss out the combobox options. Thus, by clicking button(add). It will be registered automatically in the database by default as " - SELECT -"

Comment: Then you validate the user input before allowing them to proceed

Comment: In `If combo_BIR.Items.Contains("- SELECT - ") And ` use `AndAlso` or both conditions will be evaluated, so even if the items don't contain select, you will have a `MsgBox` every time. Use `MessageBox.Show` instead of `MsgBox`. The boolean logic of `check_BIR()` can be simplified to `If touchBIR Then ... Else ... End If`

Comment: *"Common mistakes by users is that they might miss out the combobox options"*. I ask again, do you worry about them missing `TextBoxes` too? Do you put the prompt text "- Type - " in a `TextBox` just in case they miss out the `TextBox` entry? Of course you don't. You have a `Label` next to each filed so it's clear what the value is for and anyone capable of populating a `TextBox` is just as capable of populating a `ComboBox`.